# Pass dynamic props to child component in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-props

There are two components, main and update modal in my web application. I wanna the modal component can be showed immediately when enter the main page. So, when the main.vue is mounted, `showModal` is set true. However, the modal does not appear when the web enters the main page. I think `showModal` becomes true and pass to modal component. When I use vue devtool, it shows `popModal` is false. It really confuses me.

Should I change the lifecycle which setting the true value or any suggestion?

Thank you!

Main.vue

```js
<template>
  <modal :isShow="showModal"></modal>
  ...
</template>

<script>
export default {
 data () {
   return {
    showModal: false
  }
 }

 mounted() {
  //do something
  this.showModal = true
 }
}
<script>
```

Modal.vue

```js
<template>
  <modal v-if="popModal" v-model="popModal">
   <p>xxxxxx</p>
   <button @click="fn()">Click</button>
  </modal>
</template>

<script>
export default {
 props: ['isShow'],
 data () {
  return {
   popModal: this.isShow//supposed to be true
  }
 }
 methods: {
  fn() {
    this.popModal = false
  }
 }
}
<script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that data is initialized once when the component is created.
When the props isShow change, in data the old value remains.
You need to add watcher to update data

```
watch: {
  isShow(newVal, oldVal) {
    // newVal contains the updated value
    // oldVal contains the previous value
    this.popModal = newVal;
  }
}
```

Or you can make data initialize after the value has changed:

```
// Main.vue
<modal v-if="showModal" :isShow="showModal"></modal>

// Modal.vue
<modal v-model="popModal">
```

Comment: What is the value in the first suggested method?

Comment: "value" argument  is a new value of  "isShow"
https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers